# Why does NodeJs server return the same data 2 times?

Tags: node.js

I am currently learning NodeJs, thus I am building a simple NodeJs server which is called **server.js**

```
const http = require('http');
const port = 3000;
const fs = require('fs');
const sourceFile = './client/src/account.json';
var data = []
const service = http.createServer(
(req, res) => {
    var receive = "";
    var result = "";
    req.on('data', (chunk)=>{ receive += chunk })
    req.on('end', () =>{
        data = fs.readFileSync(sourceFile, 'UTF8');
        result = JSON.stringify(data);

        var data_receive = receive;
        console.log(data)

        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.write(data);
        res.end()
    })
})
service.listen(port)
```

Why does every time I request to the server, the **console.log** returns the **data** 2 times. It seems like it is looped somewhere.

This is my json file **account.json**

```
[
    {
        "id":"account_1",
        "pass":"abc123",
        "name":"Account 1"
    }
]
```

Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When performing the request from the browser, you will get an extra request for `favicon.ico`.

To avoid those double requests, handle the favicon.

```
if (req.url === '/favicon.ico') {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'image/x-icon' });
    console.log('favicon...');
    return res.end();
}

/* The rest of your code */
```